solve the error of installing code runner in vscode
[error] Unable to read file 'c:\Users\raman.vscode\extensions\formulahendry.code-runner-0.12.2\package.json' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\raman.vscode\extensions\formulahendry.code-runner-0.12.2\package.json'): Error: Unable to read file 'c:\Users\raman.vscode\extensions\formulahendry.code-runner-0.12.2\package.json' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\raman.vscode\extensions\formulahendry.code-runner-0.12.2\package.json')
at b.F (c:\Users\raman\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:58:18286)
at b.D (c:\Users\raman\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:58:18081)
at async b.C (c:\Users\raman\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:58:17393)
at async h.updateMetadata (c:\Users\raman\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:104:88184)
at async W.extractUserExtension (c:\Users\raman\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:104:120195)
at async H.pb (c:\Users\raman\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:104:114843)
this error occured while installing code runner extension in vscode

This is an error with VS Code, post it as an issue on their GitHub site.
